# hiveql remove duplicates including records that had a duplicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have a select statement that i am storing in a dataframe....

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.sql("select prty_tax_govt_issu_id from CST_EQUIFAX.eqfx_prty_emp_incm_info where emp_mtch_cd = 'Y' and emp_mtch_actv_rcrd_in = 'Y' and emp_sts_in = 'A'");
```

I then want to take this dataframe and ONLY select unique records. So determine all duplicates on the prty_tax_govt_issu_id field and if there are duplicates not only remove the duplicate(s), but the entire record that has that prty_tax_govt_issu_id

So original data frame may look like...

```
+---------------------+
|prty_tax_govt_issu_id|
+---------------------+
|            000000005|
|            000000012|
|            000000012|
|            000000028|
|            000000038|
+---------------------+
```

The new dataframe should look like....

```
|prty_tax_govt_issu_id|
+---------------------+
|            000000005|
|            000000028|
|            000000038|
+---------------------+
```

Not sure if i need to do this after I store in the dataframe or if i can just get that result in my select statement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of rows per id and select those ones with count=1.

```
val df = spark.sql("select prty_tax_govt_issu_id from CST_EQUIFAX.eqfx_prty_emp_incm_info where emp_mtch_cd = 'Y' and emp_mtch_actv_rcrd_in = 'Y' and emp_sts_in = 'A'")
// Get counts per id
val counts = df.groupBy("prty_tax_govt_issu_id").count()
// Filter for id's having only one row
counts.filter($"count" == 1).select($"prty_tax_govt_issu_id").show()
```

In SQL, you could do

```
val df = spark.sql("""
                    select prty_tax_govt_issu_id 
                    from CST_EQUIFAX.eqfx_prty_emp_incm_info
                    where emp_mtch_cd = 'Y' and emp_mtch_actv_rcrd_in = 'Y' and emp_sts_in = 'A' 
                    group by prty_tax_govt_issu_id 
                    having count(*)=1
                   """)   
df.show()
```

Comment: why do you need the count(*)=1? i think it would just add an addition parse of the result set?

Answer (score 0):

a group by clause would do it

```
select prty_tax_govt_issu_id 
from CST_EQUIFAX.eqfx_prty_emp_incm_info 
where emp_mtch_cd = 'Y' 
and emp_mtch_actv_rcrd_in = 'Y' 
and emp_sts_in = 'A'
GROUP BY prty_tax_govt_issu_id
```

Comment: dropDuplicates should work? I don't want to run a dedup on the dataframe. I just want to select unique records.

Comment: potentially, the group by will discard them as it goes, try it both ways see which has better performance.

Comment: actually, my way won't work. It's going to consider the entire record and I really just want to select unique records int he context of prty_tax_govt_issu_id. If those are identical, drop both (or more) records regardless of the other columns matching